# SwipeRefreshLayout is Not Working On Real Devices Only Works on Emulator

Tags: java, android, android-layout

activity_maian.xml

This Code Working Perfectly On Emulator But not Working on Real Devices And i can't Scroll Down Because of SwipeRefreshLayout Always comes in Middle when i am Scrolling Please Help me with this Problem

Thanks in Advance!!!

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:id="@+id/mains">

    <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/swipe">

        <WebView
            android:id="@+id/webView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="-21dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="-2dp" />



    </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/navigation_header"
        app:menu="@menu/drawer_view">

    </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

This is MainActivity I gave a normal swipe refresh layout code which is working in emulator but not in real devices..

MainActivity.java

```js
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        swipe = (SwipeRefreshLayout) findViewById(R.id.swipe);
        swipe.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRefresh() {
                LoadWed();
            }
        });
        LoadWed();

 public void LoadWed(){
        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new myWebClient());
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
        swipe.setRefreshing(true);
        webView.loadUrl("https://localhost/admin");
        webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);

        swipe.setColorSchemeResources(android.R.color.holo_blue_bright,
                android.R.color.holo_green_light,
                android.R.color.holo_orange_light,
                android.R.color.holo_red_light);
    }
```

Comment: in real device, webview is loaded ??

Comment: webview loaded but swipe refresh is not working

Comment: add swipe layout in any parent view e.g LinearLayout or RelativeLayout

Comment: i have navigation layout as parent view

Comment: @bhupathituraga, place your SwipeRefreshLayout inside `framelayout` and check.

Comment: i have done that

Answer (score 0):

Added FrameLayout as a first child of DrawerLayout. And added TextView, ProgressBar, SwipeRefreshLayout as a child of that FrameLayout and now it works as expected.

> Like This

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:id="@+id/mains">
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/swipe">
            <WebView
                android:id="@+id/webView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="-21dp"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="-2dp" />
        </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
    </FrameLayout>
    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/navigation_header"
        app:menu="@menu/drawer_view"></android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: i can't refresh on real device and when i am scrolling down refreshing icon appears